# Use of CheckBoxFor for editing model property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing an issue, I have a property logic_op of my Model Restriction:

```
   public class Restriction
   {
    public int RestrictionID{get;set;}
    public string logic_op{get;set;}
   }
```

This property can takes three values, so there is three options, So How can I implement that using checkbox of radio buttons using Html helpers ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Clarify please, You need them radio buttons or checkboxes?

Comment: Say radio Button, one choice between three options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate 3 radio buttons for property `logic_op` where the options can be "value", "value2" or "value3", you can use

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.logic_op, "value1"><span>Value1</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.logic_op, "value2"><span>Value2</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.logic_op, "value3"><span>Value3</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what I want!